# Scraping and string-formatting issue : one time scrape with '' another time with ""

Tags: python, format, beautifulsoup

This code :

```
    url="http://www.royalcanin.fr/nos-aliments/gammes-pour-chiens/tous-les-aliments-pour-chiens/les-aliments-chez-les-veterinaires/chiens-en-bonne-sante/small/chien-sterilise/neutered-adult-small-dog"## read URL from an array coming from an Url-CSV
#print(url)

page_0=urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup_0 = BeautifulSoup(page_0.read(),"html.parser") 
restricted_webpage_title_indication= soup_0.find( "div", {"class":"bloc"} ) # to get title and indication
readable_restricted_title_indication=str(restricted_webpage_title_indication)
soup_title_indication=BeautifulSoup(readable_restricted_title_indication,"html.parser")

indication=[]


for li in soup_title_indication.find_all('li'):
    indication.append(li.get_text().strip())

Pair_indication=["Indications",indication]
print(Pair_indication)
```

Gives me the following print :

```
['Indications', ['Risque de prise de poids', 'Sensibilité buccodentaire', "Risque de calculs d'oxalate et de struvite"]]
```

Why is the last element quoted with " " and not with ' ' like the previous two others ? 
The thing I don't understand here is that on the website, the three "li" are tagged and written the same way. Like this :

Risque de prise de poids

Sensibilité buccodentaire

Risque de calculs d'oxalate et de struvite

Why is that so ? What i'm i missing ? 
Thanks for your help !

Comment: Sidenote: Although some websites really should be scrapped, the term is „scraping”. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not missing anything , Python printed the last with double quotes because the body of that string already had single quote so instead of printing with single quotes and showing the inner single quote escaped , Python printed that string using double quotes .

Irrespective of that all the elements of the list are strings , and the difference is only during printing.

A very simple example to show this -

```
>>> l = ['123','12\'3']
>>> l
['123', "12'3"]
>>> repr(l[1])
'"12\'3"'
>>> print(repr(l[1]))
"12'3"
```

---

Please note above is just the way `repr()` handled it, when writing to csv, it will be handled differently and correctly by the `csv` module. Example -

```
>>> l = ['123','12\'3',"222'333"]
>>> with open('b.csv','w') as f:
...     writer = csv.writer(f,quotechar="'")
...     writer.writerow(l)
...
24
>>> with open('b.csv','r') as f:
...     reader = csv.reader(f,quotechar="'")
...     for line in reader:
...             print(line)
...
['123', "12'3", "222'333"]
[]
```

The csv file looked like -

```
123,'12''3','222''333'
```

Comment: I understand and i thank yyou for that. But it does cause problem with csv writing when `Dialect.quotechar` is set by default  to `''` doesn't it ?

Comment: is that a double quote?

Comment: A one-character string used to quote fields containing special characters, such as the delimiter or quotechar, or which contain new-line characters i get from the `csv`doc. So if quote char is '' then and the quote field contains already a '', something is gonna happen here or am i wrong ?

Comment: I do not think it would cause any issues, check the example with csv module I added.